# Possible to claim Payouts for very old Era?

Tags: staking, era, payouts

In `payoutStakers()` I see that `Era` argument needs to between `current_era` and `history_depth`. So are unclaimed payouts for very old eras effectively lost?
If they are unclaimable, then are those funds moved to treasury? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

correct, when new era triggered the underlying storage like `ErasStakers*` and `ErasValidator*` will be removed and unclaimable. Staking reward is usually a model of inflation(mint/deposit) so no transfer/move required